# How to trigger some action on specified time of node

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I have a node of custom content type and one custom field for flag of specified time. How to check time is over and perform some action when time is over.

Comment: [Scheduling Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1300068)

Comment: I have no event Means how to check my node specified date is over

Comment: Yes but you can create a scheduled event when saving content type or flagging. Otherwise you need to create a Rule to run periodically and perform action over content fetched via Views or something like that.

Comment: Create a rule using cron run as event to perform a periodic check.